# Cannot calculate times with 12:00 AM

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I have a spreadsheet the successfully adds two times together, but that has one problem. I am adding two times to get a resulting time elapsed as in this sheet:

[image: Sample sheet]

The formula I’m using (in column F) to calculate is:

```
=IF(OR(D4=0,E4=0),0,IF((E4>D4),(E4-D4),((E4+24)-D4))
```

(I then use `=HOUR(F4)+(MINUTE(F4)/60)` in column G to convert to a number I can use in other calculations)

The cell format I have been using for all three cells is category - Time:  6:00 PM

My problem… arises when, as in row 8, a value of 12 am is entered. In this case, the value in the formula bar will show 12:00:00 AM, but the cell will display as blank (I assume because zero values are set not to display) and column F will not calculate and will be blank also. Any other time but midnight works without a problem.

In order to remedy this, I have tried different number formats such as [h]:mm, but still nothing works.

Can anyone please tell me how I can enter a time of midnight / 12:00:00 AM and have it be calculated as 12, and not zero? Note: I would prefer to have times formatted as 12hr and not 24 hr.

Comment: Why not set it to display zero values? That would solve the core problem here. Then of course you'll still have the problem that you want 00:00 to be displayed as 12:00AM

Comment: Just learn about how date/time is stored in Excel. Date part is integer part of the number; hours, minutes, etc. are the fraction part. They you can think about adding 24 hours like `+1`, not `+24` (as seen in your formula).

Comment: Actually... I believe I've solved some of the issue and simplified it by instead using the formula:     =24*(E4+(D4>E4)-D4)

Comment: @rory alsop... I cannot set it to display zero values because that will not work in the majority of the other cells in the sheet, and it is part of a much larger workbook where I cannot display zeros. I did however look into conditional formatting where zeros would be displayed only on some cells, but was unsuccessful in finding a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Have played around with this to try and emulate your problem, And I think I see the issue. Try this:

I have formatted the cells to be Time - using 1:30:55PM as the specific option (the last of 5 options for Time formatting) and this works every time.

For me, if I set the time to

- 00:00
- 0
- 24
- or even to 23:60 (I was trying to make it break :-) )

it displays as 12:00:00 AM.

Answer (score 0):

Having the same problem. With a cell formatted for "1:37:30 PM" or just "1:37 PM" any entry of 12:00 am results in a blank cell displayed, even though 12:00:00 AM is shown in the formula bar.

My solution is to enter the 12:00 am as "24:00" and this successfully displays at 12:00 am under those formatting conditions, with 24:00:00 shown in the formula bar.

Answer (score 0):

Was having the same issue. Tried to change the time format to: Custom - [h]:mm and it will show you 24:00. You will be able to do calculations like that.

Answer (score 0):

To compute A2 - A1, where A2=12:00 AM and A1=8:00 PM, set B1=24:00:00 and the answer is B1+A2-A1 in h:mm format.